# Is it possible to merge the difference images using < canvas >

Tags: ajax, image, merge, canvas, vnc

I am working on developing an AJAX based application similar to VNC .. I am able to reproduce keyboard and mouse interaction from the browser to the remote machine. But when it comes to display part .. I am relying on page refresh that rederes latest captured desktop image.

I wanted to improve the display aspects by using AJAX requests to get delta of current image capture and the previously rendered image from the server .. and try to merge the delta content received in JAVA script using < canvas > to rebuild the display. If able to do so my application will be highly usable.

I would appreciate if experts would comment on feasibility and practicality of the approach.

Regards,

Parag

Comment: Could some expert please comment on this thread :(

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible. E.g. by fetching new images from the server represented as data URLs together with coordinates of where to place them using drawImage().